# Have I correctly defined the language of strings that have balanced parenthesis?

Tags: formal-languages

I am trying to learn about formal languages and I was wondering how I would go about defining the language that contains all strings which have matched parentheses and this is the definition I came up with —

$L = \{(x*)|x\in L\}\cup\{\epsilon\}$

Here, $($ and $)$ denote the literal characters '(' and ')' respectively. I use the union to make sure that the empty string is considered a valid string.

I am concerned here about whether referencing $L$ in the definition of $L$ is a meaningful thing to do, and if it isn't how I would go about defining such a language.

Comment: This expression is wrong because $x∗$ repeats the same string $x$. For instance, it does not generate $(()(()))$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing $L$ in the definition of $L$ is not meaningful, because it makes the definition self-referential/circular, which isn't kosher.  You can't define a concept in terms of the concept.  While there are structured ways to address the challenges associated with self-reference in definitions (e.g., recursively defined types, least fixed points), this can be tricky and might be best avoided at your level of experience.

A better way to define such a language is through a context-free grammar that generates this language.

--

Related: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_definition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_definition, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_fixed_point, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyck_language

Comment: Isn't a context-free grammar a way to define the language with some kind of self-reference, here?

Comment: @Nathaniel, yes, absolutely.  A CFG is likely to be less error-prone for someone who is a bit new to the field, than a circular/self-referential definition.  A CFG has a precise semantics that has been defined by experts in a way that is well-defined.  In contrast, having someone who is a bit new try to write definitions of $L$ in terms of $L$ is error-prone and has a significant risk of leading to circular/ill-defined definitions.  My aim is to offer guidance to someone a bit new to the field about what's least likely to lead them astray.